# Replace specific character/string in specific scope with regexp

Tags: regex, perl, awk, replace

e.g.

```
~cat ./temp
1,2,"3,1,2",4,5,"A,2,Csd",xx,a,"s,s,,",,,
```

After shell parse i want this output:

```
~parse.sh ./temp
1,2,"3_1_2",4,5,"A_2_Csd",xx,a,"s_s__",,,
```

i.e. 
replace all the `,` with `_` in the `"..."` scope.

Any shell solution will be welcome, awk/sed/perl/other smart thing you can think.

snippet code the shorter the better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this perl command line that transliterates commas to underscores for each match:

```
perl -pe's#"[^"]*"#$&=~y/,/_/r#ge' ./temp
```

`$&` is the whole match

`y///` is the transliteration operator (it can also be written `tr///`)

the `r` modifier returns a result string (instead of the number of replaced characters).

the `e` modifier allows to execute code in the replacement pattern.

Comment: Bravo! thx! Can you explain `$&=~y/,/_/r` this part in detail or get a link about what this syntax meaning? 3Q~

Comment: @hedleyyan: Note that if you have to deal with more complex cases (fields with newlines, escaped quotes), build a simple script with the module Text::CSV.